# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when inserting node at front

Tags: c

Below is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct NodeTag {
  int value;
  struct NodeTag *next;
};

typedef struct NodeTag Node;

typedef struct  {
  Node *head;
  int length;
} List;


void insertAtHead( List *list, int val )
{

  Node **link = &( list->head );


    Node  *n = NULL;
    n = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->next  = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    n->value = val;




  n->next->value = (*link)->value;



  list->head = &n;


  list->length++;
}

void insertAtTail( List *list, int val )
{

  Node **link = &( list->head );


  while ((*link)->next != NULL){
      (*link) = (*link)->next;
  }


  Node n;
  n.value = val;


  n.next = NULL;


  (*link)->next = &n;


  list->length++;
}


void insertSorted( List *list, int val )
{

  Node **link = &( list->head );


  while ((*link)->next != NULL){
      (*link) = (*link)->next;
  }


  Node n;
  n.value = val;


  n.next = (*link)->next;


  (*link)->next = &n;


  list->length++;
}

/** Print out the size and contents of the given list. */
void printList( List *list )
{

  printf( "%d elements :", list->length );

  for ( Node *n = list->head; n; n = n->next )
    printf( " %d", n->value );
  printf( "\n" );

}

void freeList( List *list )
{
  while ( list->head ) {
    Node *n = list->head;
    list->head = n->next;
    free( n );
  }


  list->head = NULL;
  list->length = 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  FILE *fp;
  if ( argc != 2 || ( fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
    printf( "Can't open file: %s\n", argv[ 1 ] );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  {
    List list = { NULL, 0 };

    int val;
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val ) == 1 )
      insertAtHead( &list, val );

    printList( &list );

    freeList( &list );
  }

  fseek( fp, SEEK_SET, 0 );

  {
    List list = { NULL, 0 };

    int val;
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val ) == 1 )
      insertAtTail( &list, val );

    printList( &list );

    freeList( &list );
  }

  fseek( fp, SEEK_SET, 0 );

  {
    List list = { NULL, 0 };

    int val;
    while ( fscanf( fp, "%d", &val ) == 1 )
      insertSorted( &list, val );

    printList( &list );

    freeList( &list );
  }
  fclose( fp );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and the following line is giving me ECX_BAD_ACCESS error when debugging:

```
  n->next->value = (*link)->value;
```

To my knowledge I am mallocing the current node and the next node for it so I am not sure why the error is showing. Does anybody have any idea? Am I supposed to have a for loop to iterate through entire linked list and malloc each node?

Comment: Check the value of `*link`. That is, consider the value of `list->head` the first time `insertAtHead` is called.

Comment: `n = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));` Do *not* cast the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: OT: regarding the expression: `argc != 2`  This should be checked before checking if a file was successfully opened.  For one reason,  never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user.  Otherwise, the code will be accessing the memory at address 0 to obtain the file name.  This 'usually' results in a seg fault event.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf( "Can't open file: %s\n", argv[ 1 ] );`  Error messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout`.  and when the error indication is from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` was made for this activity

Answer (score 0):

Consider these 3 lines in the order they're executed:

```
List list = { NULL, 0 };  // in `main`

insertAtTail( &list, val ); // in `main`

Node **link = &( list->head ); // in `insertAtTail`
```

Since `list->head` is `NULL`, `*link` is `NULL`.

Then once the `n->next->value = (*link)->value;` line is executed, you're dereferencing a null pointer.